# How to replace js stack trace to include "line" and "position" text?

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a javascript stacktrace that we write to the screen during development.

```
 (OurCustom.js?635095252297740283:14:29)
    at jquery-1.8.3.min.js?634937263102341783:2:11602
    at Function.v.extend.map (jquery-1.8.3.min.js?634937263102341783:2:15448)
```

I am trying to replace the last two colons from

```
(OurCustom.js?635095252297740283:14:29)
```

to

```
(OurCustom.js?635095252297740283 line 14 pos 29)
```

My attempt is not working. Nothing is replaced.

```
stackMessage = stackMessage.replace(/_(:\d*)(:\d*)_/g, "line $1 pos $2");
```

*Edit: BTW, this is how I get my stacktrace. (with the correct answer)*

```
catch (err)
{
    var stackMessage = (err.stack || err.stacktrace || "")
                       .replace(/:(\d*):(\d*)/g, " line $1 pos $2");
...
{
```

Comment: And where are there `_` in the original string?

Comment: yes, i thought they were escape chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with those underscores in your regex. You should use

```
stackMessage = stackMessage.replace(/:(\d*):(\d*)/g, " line $1 pos $2")
```

Comment: you were like 10 secs ahead of me!

Comment: cheers. Picked up those underscores accidentally from another SO question. Thought they were for escaping the brackets for the replace. Thanks for repositioning the colon too.